# How to set up new class file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class

I am trying to clean up my code by moving some to different classes in Swift. However, I'm getting confused by initializers when setting up the class. I want to pass just position parameter and size parameter when setting up a new rectangle.

```
    let rectangle = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width:390, height:200))
    rectangle.position = CGPointMake(frame.midX-10, frame.midY + 50)
    rectangle.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    rectangle.glowWidth = 1.0
    rectangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFromPath: rectangle.path!)
    rectangle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(rectangle)
```

My attempt:

```
class Walls: SKSpriteNode {
var size = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width:390, height:200))

init(postition: CGPoint, size: CGSize) {
    super.init(color:SKColor.blackColor())
    self.size = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width:390, height:200))
    self.position = CGPointMake(frame.midX-10, frame.midY + 50)
    self.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    self.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
}

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your attempt?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: It did, thanks! What would be the argument for Walls() to use it in my GameScene class though?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Walls: SKSpriteNode {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        didLoad()
    }

    func didLoad() {
        let rectangle = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width:390, height:200))
        rectangle.position = CGPointMake(frame.midX-10, frame.midY + 50)
        rectangle.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        rectangle.glowWidth = 1.0
        rectangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFromPath: rectangle.path!)
        rectangle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    }
}
```